# Proper way of applying function on array of points

Tags: python, function, numpy

I've coding a Python script manipulating points in 2d dimensions and I'm not happy about the way I wrote a few lines giving me the distance of these points to a specific point, of coordinates (X_0,Y_0) in the following:

```
def f(x):
    return sqrt((x[1]-X_0)**2+(x[0]-Y_0)**2)
distances = N.zeros((n_points),dtype=float) #array that will contain the distances after calculation
for temp_x,temp_i in zip(my_points,range(n_points)): #my_points my array of points of shape (2,n_points)
    distances[temp_i] = f(temp_x)
```

This script works but I would prefer something neater, working with a different function f and then simply:

```
distances = f(m_points)
```

without loop and without having to define distances before.

My problem is with the definition of f, I already wrote mappings from 1d to 1d arrays by use of numpy.vectorize but never, 2d to 1d.

Maybe using a `lambda` instruction this time?

EDIT: While writing down my question I actually had the idea of doing it using a `map(lambda ...` which seems to give me what I want:

```
distances =  map(lambda (x,y): sqrt((x-X_0)**2+(y-Y_0)**2),my_points)
```

Doesn't look any complicated now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading your question it seems your two main concerns are the defined function and the for loop.

Firstly, I like your solution of a properly defined function. While this task can be accomplished with lambda, that complex of a solution can be be very congested in a labda expression. Nevertheless,

`lambda x : sqrt((x[1]-X_0)**2+(x[0]-Y_0)**2)` ,

is the expression you are looking for.

Secondly, I think the built-in `map()` function is the perfect replacement for your for loop. Documentation for `map` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

In conclusion, your one-line solution to the problem would be:

`distances = map(lambda x : sqrt((x[1]-X_0)**2+(x[0]-Y_0)**2), my_points)`

Comment: Yes! I went for that, using lambda only came to my mind when writing down this question (it can turn quite fruitful to put words on your obstacles when stuck). Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this answers your problem ?

```
import numpy as np

def distance(P,P0):
    return np.sqrt( (P[:,0]-P0[0])**2 + (P[:,1]-P0[1])**2)

# Draw 100 random points
P = np.random.uniform(0,100,(10,2))

# Point to measure distance to
P0 = (50,50)

# Print all distances
print distance(P,P0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, indeed `numpy.sqrt` would be a valuable solution in this case. I chose to use `lambda` in the end though.

Comment: Vectorizing, as in this example, is efficient. Using `map` and `lambda` expressions where vectorization is possible is many other things: more complicated, awful to look at, extremely slow and bad practice.

Comment: This is the way of doing this. Period. It can be made slightly more efficient an flexible by doing: `delta = P - P0; return np.sqrt(np.sum(delta*delta, axis=-1))` but that's an implementation detail compared to the OPs very wrong decision. It seems GvR [was right](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) after all...